# Plotly: Dodge overlapping points on scatterplot categorical axis

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I am trying to use plotly to compare the coefficents of regression models using error bars for the confidence intervals. I used the following code to plot it, using the variable as a categorical `y` axis in a scatter plot. The problem is that the points are overlapping, and I'd like to dodge them like happens in bar charts when you set `barmode='group'`. If I had a numerical axis I could manually dodge them, but I can't do that.

```
fig = px.scatter(
        df, y='index', x='coef', text='label', color='model',
        error_x_minus='lerr', error_x='uerr',
        hover_data=['coef', 'pvalue', 'lower', 'upper']
    )
fig.update_traces(textposition='top center')
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
```

[image]

Using facets I get almost the result I want, but some of the labels goes off-plot and are not visible:

```
fig = px.scatter(
    df, y='model', x='coef', text='label', color='model',
    facet_row='index',
    error_x_minus='lerr', error_x='uerr',
    hover_data=['coef', 'pvalue', 'lower', 'upper']
)
fig.update_traces(textposition='top center')
fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=a.text.split("=")[-1]))
```

[image]

Somebody has any idea or workaround for either dodging points in the first case or displaying labels in the second case?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Here's the random fake dataframe I made to generate the plots:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'coef': {0: 1.0018729737113143,
  1: 0.9408864645423858,
  2: 0.29796556981484884,
  3: -0.6844053575764955,
  4: -0.13689631932690113,
  5: 0.1473096200402363,
  6: 0.9564712505670716,
  7: 0.956099003887811,
  8: 0.33319108930207175,
  9: -0.7022778825729681,
  10: -0.1773916842612131,
  11: 0.09485417304851751},
 'index': {0: 'const',
  1: 'x1',
  2: 'x2',
  3: 'x3',
  4: 'x4',
  5: 'x5',
  6: 'const',
  7: 'x1',
  8: 'x2',
  9: 'x3',
  10: 'x4',
  11: 'x5'},
 'label': {0: '1.002***',
  1: '0.941***',
  2: '0.298***',
  3: '-0.684***',
  4: '-0.137',
  5: '0.147',
  6: '0.956***',
  7: '0.956***',
  8: '0.333***',
  9: '-0.702***',
  10: '-0.177',
  11: '0.095'},
 'lerr': {0: 0.19788416996400904,
  1: 0.19972987383410545,
  2: 0.0606849959013587,
  3: 0.1772734289533593,
  4: 0.1988122854078155,
  5: 0.21870366703236832,
  6: 0.2734783191688098,
  7: 0.2760291042678362,
  8: 0.08386739920069491,
  9: 0.2449940255063039,
  10: 0.27476098595116555,
  11: 0.3022511162310027},
 'lower': {0: 0.8039888037473053,
  1: 0.7411565907082803,
  2: 0.23728057391349014,
  3: -0.8616787865298547,
  4: -0.33570860473471664,
  5: -0.07139404699213203,
  6: 0.6829929313982618,
  7: 0.6800698996199748,
  8: 0.24932369010137684,
  9: -0.947271908079272,
  10: -0.45215267021237865,
  11: -0.2073969431824852},
 'model': {0: 'OLS',
  1: 'OLS',
  2: 'OLS',
  3: 'OLS',
  4: 'OLS',
  5: 'OLS',
  6: 'QuantReg',
  7: 'QuantReg',
  8: 'QuantReg',
  9: 'QuantReg',
  10: 'QuantReg',
  11: 'QuantReg'},
 'pvalue': {0: 1.4211692095019375e-16,
  1: 4.3583690618389965e-15,
  2: 6.278403727223468e-16,
  3: 1.596372747840846e-11,
  4: 0.17483151363955116,
  5: 0.18433051296752084,
  6: 4.877385844808361e-10,
  7: 6.665860891682504e-10,
  8: 5.476882838731488e-12,
  9: 1.4240852942202845e-07,
  10: 0.20303143985022934,
  11: 0.5347222575215599},
 'uerr': {0: 0.19788416996400904,
  1: 0.19972987383410556,
  2: 0.06068499590135873,
  3: 0.1772734289533593,
  4: 0.19881228540781554,
  5: 0.21870366703236832,
  6: 0.27347831916880994,
  7: 0.2760291042678362,
  8: 0.08386739920069491,
  9: 0.2449940255063039,
  10: 0.27476098595116555,
  11: 0.3022511162310027},
 'upper': {0: 1.1997571436753234,
  1: 1.1406163383764913,
  2: 0.35865056571620757,
  3: -0.5071319286231362,
  4: 0.0619159660809144,
  5: 0.3660132870726046,
  6: 1.2299495697358815,
  7: 1.2321281081556472,
  8: 0.41705848850276667,
  9: -0.4572838570666642,
  10: 0.09736930168995245,
  11: 0.3971052892795202}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close to a working solution with your second attempt. Just make more room for your labels with:

```
height=600, width=800
```

And then place the labels for the traces named `'OLS'` within the boundaries of each subplot with:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(textposition='bottom center') if t.name == 'OLS' else ())
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'coef': {0: 1.0018729737113143,
  1: 0.9408864645423858,
  2: 0.29796556981484884,
  3: -0.6844053575764955,
  4: -0.13689631932690113,
  5: 0.1473096200402363,
  6: 0.9564712505670716,
  7: 0.956099003887811,
  8: 0.33319108930207175,
  9: -0.7022778825729681,
  10: -0.1773916842612131,
  11: 0.09485417304851751},
 'index': {0: 'const',
  1: 'x1',
  2: 'x2',
  3: 'x3',
  4: 'x4',
  5: 'x5',
  6: 'const',
  7: 'x1',
  8: 'x2',
  9: 'x3',
  10: 'x4',
  11: 'x5'},
 'label': {0: '1.002***',
  1: '0.941***',
  2: '0.298***',
  3: '-0.684***',
  4: '-0.137',
  5: '0.147',
  6: '0.956***',
  7: '0.956***',
  8: '0.333***',
  9: '-0.702***',
  10: '-0.177',
  11: '0.095'},
 'lerr': {0: 0.19788416996400904,
  1: 0.19972987383410545,
  2: 0.0606849959013587,
  3: 0.1772734289533593,
  4: 0.1988122854078155,
  5: 0.21870366703236832,
  6: 0.2734783191688098,
  7: 0.2760291042678362,
  8: 0.08386739920069491,
  9: 0.2449940255063039,
  10: 0.27476098595116555,
  11: 0.3022511162310027},
 'lower': {0: 0.8039888037473053,
  1: 0.7411565907082803,
  2: 0.23728057391349014,
  3: -0.8616787865298547,
  4: -0.33570860473471664,
  5: -0.07139404699213203,
  6: 0.6829929313982618,
  7: 0.6800698996199748,
  8: 0.24932369010137684,
  9: -0.947271908079272,
  10: -0.45215267021237865,
  11: -0.2073969431824852},
 'model': {0: 'OLS',
  1: 'OLS',
  2: 'OLS',
  3: 'OLS',
  4: 'OLS',
  5: 'OLS',
  6: 'QuantReg',
  7: 'QuantReg',
  8: 'QuantReg',
  9: 'QuantReg',
  10: 'QuantReg',
  11: 'QuantReg'},
 'pvalue': {0: 1.4211692095019375e-16,
  1: 4.3583690618389965e-15,
  2: 6.278403727223468e-16,
  3: 1.596372747840846e-11,
  4: 0.17483151363955116,
  5: 0.18433051296752084,
  6: 4.877385844808361e-10,
  7: 6.665860891682504e-10,
  8: 5.476882838731488e-12,
  9: 1.4240852942202845e-07,
  10: 0.20303143985022934,
  11: 0.5347222575215599},
 'uerr': {0: 0.19788416996400904,
  1: 0.19972987383410556,
  2: 0.06068499590135873,
  3: 0.1772734289533593,
  4: 0.19881228540781554,
  5: 0.21870366703236832,
  6: 0.27347831916880994,
  7: 0.2760291042678362,
  8: 0.08386739920069491,
  9: 0.2449940255063039,
  10: 0.27476098595116555,
  11: 0.3022511162310027},
 'upper': {0: 1.1997571436753234,
  1: 1.1406163383764913,
  2: 0.35865056571620757,
  3: -0.5071319286231362,
  4: 0.0619159660809144,
  5: 0.3660132870726046,
  6: 1.2299495697358815,
  7: 1.2321281081556472,
  8: 0.41705848850276667,
  9: -0.4572838570666642,
  10: 0.09736930168995245,
  11: 0.3971052892795202}})

fig = px.scatter(
    df, y='model', x='coef', text='label', color='model',
    facet_row='index',
    error_x_minus='lerr', error_x='uerr',
    hover_data=['coef', 'pvalue', 'lower', 'upper'],
    height=600, width=800,
)
fig.update_traces(textposition='top center')
fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=a.text.split("=")[-1]))

fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(textposition='bottom center') if t.name == 'OLS' else ())

fig.show()
```